# Can't get background image to show up on website

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I'm trying to put a timeline on my website but can't seem to get my background image to show up.

What I've tried:

1. checking the path of my image
2. matching the height of my divs/HTML elements to make sure the image is covering the right height
3. made sure I put background-image in my HTML tags
4. tried using a negative value for top to move the image around - didn't work

I also tried deleting my other styling elements and adding them back in to see if they were causing it. I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong.

The CSS element I'm wrestling with is called t1-bg (located at bottom of CSS sheet) - here is my code:

(run the snippet in a full window for a proper overview)

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#FF9940, white);
  font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 53px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px grey;
  background-color: #1E2752;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  color: #FCFCFF;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 19px 16px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  right: -100px;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #FF9940;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

ul {
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 28px;
  left: 23px;
  right: 23px;
  width: 100%;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

h2 p {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.right-button {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 47px
}

.other-button {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#timeline {
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.75;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 650px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #031625;
}

.t1-item:before,
.t1-item:after {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.t1-item {
  padding: 25px;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 20rem;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
}

.t1-item:after {
  background: rgba(3, 22, 37, 0.85);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.t1-item:before {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 75%);
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) translateY(50%);
  transition: opacity .5s ease, transform .5s ease;
}

.t1-item:hover {
  width: 30%;
}

.t1-item:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.t1-item:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) translateY(0);
  transition: opacity 1s ease, transform 1s ease .25s;
}

.t1-item:hover .t1-content {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: all .75s ease .5s;
}

.t1-item:hover .t1-bg {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}

.t1-content {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) translateY(25px);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.1618em;
  top: 55%;
  opacity: 0%;
}

.t1-content h3 {
  font-family: tahoma;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #1779cf;
  font-size: 1.44rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.t1-year {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.t1-year p {
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 1.628rem;
  line-height: 0;
}

.t1-bg {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  transition: filter .5se ease;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Isabelle Kreienbrink </title>
  <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Isabelle Kreienbrink </h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="#academics">Academics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
    <li class="right-button"><a href="#contacts">Contact Info</a></li>
    <li class="other-button"><a href="#other">Test</a></li>
    <li class="other-button"><a href="#other">Testing</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h2> Welcome to my website!
    <p> I hope you learn a little about me while you're here. </p>
  </h2>



  <section id="timeline">
    <div class="t1-item">
      <div class="t1-bg" style="background-image:url(https://www.eschoolnews.com/files/2016/12/computer-science-education-600x400.jpg)">
      </div>

      <div class="t1-year">
        <p class="f2 heading">2014</p>
      </div>

      <div class="t1-content">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p>
          test
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>



    <div class="t1-item">
      <div class="t1-bg" style="background-image:url(https://www.eschoolnews.com/files/2016/12/computer-science-education-600x400.jpg)"></div>

      <div class="t1-year">
        <p class="f2 heading">2015</p>
      </div>

      <div class="t1-content">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p>
          test
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="t1-item">
      <div class="t1-bg" style="background-image:url(001.jpeg)"></div>

      <div class="t1-year">
        <p class="f2 heading">2016</p>
      </div>

      <div class="t1-content">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p>
          test
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>



  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: seems like the element has no width or height and no content

Comment: @epascarello yes I tried trouble shooting that as I mentioned above (unsuccessfully). I made the height and width of my t1-bg element the same as the #timeline element and saw no results. Also, there is content. I have a link to the image. the background image is the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone mentioned in a comment on your question, you have no height set on your div. It does in fact have no content. A css background image does not count as content in the html. You can easily prove this by creating a simple html file with just your div in it. If you do the following, there will be no image:

```
<div class="t1-bg" style="background-image:url(https://www.eschoolnews.com/files/2016/12/computer-science-education-600x400.jpg)"></div>
```

Add height and width and the image will appear:

```
<div class="t1-bg" style="background-image:url(https://www.eschoolnews.com/files/2016/12/computer-science-education-600x400.jpg); height: 100%; width: 100%"></div>
```

Comment: I see what you mean about the content now. What you're saying about the height makes logical sense, as when I troubleshooted I added height in (and width) and it still wasn't showing up, so I turned to stack overflow. I just now added in the height:100% as well (just to make sure) as you suggested, and it didn't show up.

Comment: Playing around with your actual code, I also had to set width to 100%. I took your HTML and made test.html file on my computer. The only change I made was to remove your linked style sheet and embed the CSS you provided. Then I set height and width to 100% and the image appears.

Comment: That got it to work! Do you by chance know why my picture will only go up half the column? I tried moving it up with the top property and it acts like there is a bar halfway up the column, and it won't go past the "bar".